# Yajra Datatables HTML Builder, Requested unknown parameter

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

Im very new at this yajra datatable but I know that the error is cuz by the `null` value on the row. and I already tried the one that is suggested in the [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) and add default content.

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('testdatatable-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('frtip')
                ->orderBy(1)
                ->parameters([
                    "columns" => [
                        'data' => NULL,
                        'defaultContent'=> "",
                    ]
                ])
                ->buttons(
                    Button::make('create'),
                    Button::make('export'),
                    Button::make('print'),
                    Button::make('reset'),
                    Button::make('reload')
                );
}
```

but its still giving me the Request Unknown Parameter alert error. I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

[You should read the actual yajra datatable documentation because it is created for the Laravel environment itself.](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/engine-query)

Also, you should post the `.blade` file too.